# tf.nn.relu vs. tf.contrib.layers.relu?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I see this "tf.nn.relu" documented here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu

But then I also see usage of tf.contrib.layers.relu on this page in "model_fn":
https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators

It seems like the latter isn't described like the first one in an API-like fashion, but only presented in use.

Why is this? Are the docs out of date? Why have two - is one old and no longer supported/going to be removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same thing.

The latter is not an activation function but a [`fully_connected`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected) **layer** that has its activation function preset as `nn.relu`:

```
relu = functools.partial(fully_connected, activation_fn=nn.relu)
# ^                                                     |<   >|
# |_ tf.contrib.layers.relu                     tf.nn.relu_|
```

---

If you read the docs for [`contrib.layers`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers), you'll find:

> Aliases for `fully_connected` which set a default activation function
>   are available: `relu`, `relu6` and `linear`.

Summarily, [`tf.contrib.layers.relu`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4433079e7f317724eaa92ec120c6b1c3c0c52f2f/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L2137) is an alias for a [`fully_connected`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected) layer with *relu* activation while `tf.nn.relu` is the REctified Linear Unit activation function itself.

Answer (score 2):

During the [2017 TensorFlow Dev Summit](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKGc_NBoIhTn2Qhraji53cv), the `tf.contrib` section of the TensorFlow project was described as a testing ground for higher level functions.  These functions are for the community to use and test.  However, there is no guarantee that there won't be changes to the interface when functions are moved to tf.core.  Between Tensorflow versions r0.12 at r1.0, many of the `tf.contrib.layer` functions were moved to `tf.layers` (which did not exist before r1.0).  In short, documentation of tf.contrib will never by as good as tf.core.