# tf.nn.relu vs tf.keras.activations.relu

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I see both [tf.nn.relu](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu) and [tf.keras.activations.relu](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/relu) computes only the ReLU function (no additional fully connected layer or something, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773379/tf-nn-relu-vs-tf-contrib-layers-relu)), so what's the difference between them? Does one just wraps the other?

Answer (score 11):

- `tf.nn.relu` : It comes from TensorFlow library. It is located in the `nn` module. Hence, it is used as an operation in neural networks. If `x` is a tensor then,

  ```
  y = tf.nn.relu( x )
  ```

  It is used in creating custom layers and NN. If you use it with Keras, you may face some problems while loading or saving the models or converting the model to TF Lite.
- `tf.keras.activations.relu` : It comes from the Keras library included in TensorFlow. It is located in the `activations` module which also provides another activation functions. It is mostly used in Keras Layers ( `tf.keras.layers` ) for the `activation=` argument :

  ```
  model.add( keras.layers.Dense( 25 , activation=tf.keras.activations.relu  ) )
  ```

  But, it can also be used as the example in the above section. It is more specific to Keras ( `Sequential` or `Model` ) rather than raw TensorFlow computations.

> `tf.nn.relu` is a TensorFlow specific whereas `tf.keras.activations.relu` has more uses in Keras own library. If I create a NN with only TF,  I will most probably use `tf.nn.relu` and if I am creating a Keras Sequential model then I will use `tf.keras.activations.relu`.