# difference calling activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, activation-function

While I'm study tensorflow, I got a question.

There are two way to define activation function.

activation = 'relu' and activation = tf.nn.relu

I want to know difference between of them.

(Actually, I think other activation functions are include in this case.)

I tried two way.

First one is

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Second one is

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

I think they gave me same result.

What is the difference of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same. Keras did this to give a clearer UX for users if they don't want to customize the inner workings if a function.

[This line of code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/layers/core/dense.py#L125) from the Dense layer gets the activation function from the `activations` file. In the `activations` file, you can see that this [`relu`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/activations.py#L281) function is wrapped with `@keras_export`, which means "you can specify it as a string".

Some users might want to specify additional params like `tf.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.5)`, that's why both ways exist, and you can use either way.

Answer (score 0):

using `activation='relu'` is a shorthand for `activation=tf.keras.activations.relu`. so one is from the TF's library and the other from Keras. So which one you should use depends on whether you would use TF to create a NN or use keras to make a sequential model. For more detail you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54761708/).